# How to debug page caching?

Tags: 8, caching

I've got a page which returns `X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache: UNCACHEABLE`, I've got a suspicion that this is related to a view that is embedded in the page. Though, this made me wonder; is there any way to see what invalidated actually the page cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the answer from CG Monroe, enabling the header will show you what contexts you have, a user or session cache context can for example disable caching as well as a max-age 0.

Tracking down exactly where they are coming from can be tricky, I usually debug on the merge methods of the Cache class with a breakpoint set on having the problematic context/age. Certain filters/sorts or so (e.g. a random sort) can cause this, but so can certain block conditions (there is actually a known issue with that, see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2521956).

Comment: Thanks, I got to the point that I managed to find the `user` context that has been set. This makes the `DynamicPageCacheSubscriber->shouldCacheResponse()` say that this page is not cacheable. I'm still not sure where this context is being set. When I use `if(in_array("user", $a))` in the merge method of `Cache` I get tons of hits... Not sure why and how.

Comment: Yes, that is always a bit tricky. Usually it is the first hit, because then it often gets merged and merged again with other things many times. From that first call, check the parents and parent structures, which is only really doable with a real debugger and not just some inline debugging code. What we need is something that exposes cache tags and contexts on each render array element similar to twig debug. I think Wim once started with some ideas in https://www.drupal.org/project/renderviz. As you can see "More" unfortunatley never came, but maybe that there is already helpful?

Comment: Renderviz is definitely a useful tool! Thanks for that one.

Comment: I also found that placing a breakpoint in the `Cache::mergeContexts` method helps, but make sure that you first disable render caching in your local settings override file. Otherwise the real source of what added the context to begin with can be obscured.

Answer (score 7):

The X-Drupal-Cache-Tags header should help with this.  Here's how to enable it from [this doc](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/responses/cacheableresponseinterface#debugging):

> You can debug cacheable responses (responses that implement this
>   interface, which may be cached by Page Cache or Dynamic Page Cache) by
>   setting the http.response.debug_cacheability_headers container
>   parameter to true, in your services.yml. Followed by a container
>   rebuild, which is necessary when changing a container parameter.
>
> That will cause Drupal to send X-Drupal-Cache-Tags and
>   X-Drupal-Cache-Contexts headers.

Comment: What the heck does "a container rebuild" mean?

Comment: A full cache clear of the Drupal site.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm completely baffled as to why they didn't use that extremely-well-understood terminology.  I don't think it's just me, either -- a web search for "container rebuild" turned up https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!DrupalKernel.php/class/DrupalKernel/ and a bunch of completely irrelevant stuff about docker.  AFAICS this terminology isn't being used anywhere outside of very niche discussions of the deep internals of Drupal, so I've no idea why they'd expect readers to know that.